# Shorthand code for multiple "or" statements inside the if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a way to shorten the following

```
if (a === b || a === c || a === d)
```

down to something like

```
if (a === b || c || d)
```

The issue with the last section is it will test if `a === b`, or if `c` is `true`, or if `d` is `true`.

Comment: it depends on the values of the variables.

Comment: @Quentin If that is the only way to go about doing this, then it would use more code to create the object than just leaving it how I originally had it.

Comment: `[a, b, c, d, e, f, ...].some(function (a, i, aa) { return i && aa[0] === a; })` works for any length.